# How to remove AdMob from a project?

Tags: android, admob

How to remove AdMob from Android Studio project?
Easy please, I'm not an expert, thank you.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information regarding this

Answer (score 3):

Good day Jean, 
it depends on how old is an implementation of AdMob in your application.
Based on AdMob docs, in your module `build.gradle` should be something like

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:XXX'
```

or

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:XXX'
```

So

1. remove it and refresh Gradle (File > Sync project with Gradle files)
2. if you get errors in the app on missing AdMob library, so fix it